# HTML5 video working partially in firefox 17

Tags: html, firefox, video

i have a html5 video embedded in a web page, that appears with a fade when an user clicks on a link.
If i click on play, the timeline cursor jumps to the end, not playing anything.
If i click on the timeline (so seeking) the video starts from the point where i click and plays normally.
I already added the video formats in the .htaccess.
How can i fix this?
On chrome it works as intended.

```
<video width="660" height="275" controls="controls">
     <source type="video/webm" src="video/nev.webm"/>
     <source type="video/mp4" src="video/nev.mp4"/>
     <source type="video/ogv" src="video/nev.ogv"/>
     <source type="video/flash" src="video/nev.flv"/>
</video>
```

Roby

Answer (score 0):

I fixed changing video converter, i used "Miro Converter" and it was creating this problem, "Any Video Converter" converted the video making it work in firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is the dimension of movies, specially the format. While I was using 600 x 480 px everything play perfect, but beyond of this relation the timeline cursor doesn't works in autoplay unless I " push " the cursor 5 sec. forward .... I also use Miro video converter.